# Webpack definePlugin equivalent for babel-node

Tags: webpack, server-side-rendering, babel-node

I'm creating an SSR React app, I'm using `babel-node` for server and webpack for client. I'm facing sharing/accessing env variables. For client (webpack), I use `webpack.DefinePlugin` and access `.env` with `fetch(`${API_V1}/get-product`), Without` process.env`

But not able to do the same on `babel-node`. I don't want to update all the files with `process.env.API_V1` and just want to access envs like API_V1.

Is there any plugin or method to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

More Info

```
ReferenceError: WEB_URL is not defined
```

Comment: Do you mean trying to read the env file as running on node env (server side)?

Comment: @tmhao2005 thanks for quick reply. On client side i use webpack's definePlugin. and on server dotenv. But the syntax is different to access envs on both platforms. I want to keep the client side syntax, i.e direct using the var name 'WEB_URL' for example. Not able to achieve it on server. Please help!

Comment: Ah I see. Why don’t you set that value as global such as global.URL = something at the entry point of your server side?